# Update en Excel usando ADODB desde VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Puedo leer los datos de un Excel en una carpeta compartida usando un `Recordset` con `ADODB`; puedo escribir esos datos en un archivo local, pero de la forma `Range().Value`. No he podido hacerlo usando un `Update` con `ADODB`.

Esta es mi conexión:

```
Dim cnCaja As ADODB.Connection
Set cnCaja = New ADODB.Connection
cnCaja.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
    "Data Source='" & esteLibro & "';" & _
        "Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;ReadOnly=False';"
```

La idea es que sea algo parametrizada y con filtros, pero para simplificar el problema:

```
consUpdate = "Update [Base$A3:T100000] set INVERSIONES = 10000"
```

Y finalmente la parte que debiera hacer algo:

```
Dim rsCaja As ADODB.Recordset
Set rsCaja = New ADODB.Recordset

rsCaja.Open consUpdate, cnCaja, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
```

No da error ni dice nada.

¿Qué me falta para que el campo `INVERSIONES` se llene de 10000?

Answer (score 0):

Para la posteridad, el código funciona, pero en otro archivo. La variable `esteLibro` se contruye como:

```
Dim libro As Workbook
Set libro = ActiveWorkbook
esteLibro = libro.Name
```

Pero aunque lo ejecuto desde un libro, escribe en otro libro (copia) que está en Mis Documentos. Ahora tengo el problema de que, si coloco el libro con ruta, para estar seguro del libro en el que escribo, me dice que "Access no encuentra el Objeto", pero ese es otro cuento...